# Update creating a new record if values are not modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The code is working fine if I edit and change the value but if I update the same value it creates a new record.

I am just following the ruby tutorials and am stuck on this issue. I am fairly new to ruby and rails.

Controller : articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def create
    #render plain: params[:article].inspect
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @articles = Article.all    
end

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title_article, :text_article, :author_article)
  end

end
```

Form : _form.html.erb

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title_article ,"Title" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title_article %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :text_article ,"Content" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text_article %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :author_article ,"Author" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :author_article %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

New Article Page: new.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Page</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Edit Article Page: edit.html.erb

```
<h1>New Page</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Comment: On the update interface when you enter the same thing again in fields then above code insert new record not updating ?

Comment: Please show your form as well.

Comment: @Ansar yeah. On the edit page if I do not make any changes and press Submit it creates a new record whereas when I change something it modifies the same record.

Comment: Can you check your console for the parameters sent to the server ? Especially, is the `id` sent the expected value ? Also are you sure it really submits a new record and it's not just a HTML duplicate ?

Comment: Emm... also where is your `<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>` ??

Answer (score 0):

As @Cyril DD is saying in the comment, your code in _form.html.erb should have `<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>` at the first line. (I guess it should have raised syntax error...)

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
...
```

I copied all of your codes and added the line. Then, everything worked fine. It didn't make a new article even when no value was changed in editing.